# Kernel dies when using itertools.permutation

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings. And I want to find all possible combination of that list. I use itertools.permutation and it runs for while but then it crashes saying **Kernel died, restarting**. I try running the code through terminal too. But it crashes there too. Here is my code:

```
import itertools


sum_stats = ['pi', 'theta W','Tajima D','distVar','distSkew','distKurt','nDiplos',
         'diplo_H1','diplo_H12','diplo_H2/H1','diplo_ZnS','diplo_Omega']

permuted_sum_stats = list(itertools.permutations(sum_stats))
```

Can someone show me an efficient way to create all possible combinations of this list?

Comment: Hello, you are trying to put factorial 12 elements in memory with `list`. This is 479,001,600 elements, which is a lot. Using `itertools` you may not need to store it in a list

Comment: How do I store it then?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. You can iterate over it without putting it in a list `for stats in itertools.permutations(sum_stats): do_something() `

Answer (score 2):

Your list has 12 elements. To get all possible permutations, your new list needs 12!, or about 500 million elements. One of these lists takes about 150 bytes, excluding the space of the strings, which I assume is reused.

This leads to about 75 GB of data, which is probably more than the RAM of your machine.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too. Could you suggest another approach by which I can do that?

Comment: Can you tell me _why_ you want a list of all permutations?

Comment: I have matrices of size 12 x 11 where each row corresponds to one of the variables in sum_stats in the matrix. When I train my convolution neural network based on a specific order of sum_stats, it gives me test accuracy of 94% but the moment I change the order of sum_stats in the test matrices, its accuracy drops. I thought if I could train my network using different images where I use different ordering of sum_stats, it'll become more robust to these perturbations. So I needed the list of all perturbations so that I could perturb the rows in my matrices accordingly.